# Selenium JAVA: Clicking on a element within a menu with no ID

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am busy using Selenium on SSRS reports.
I am struggling with a specific element within a menu which I cannot get to interact with

Here is a html snippit.

```
</div><div class="DisabledButton">
<a title="Excel" class="ActiveLink"      onclick="$find('ctl31').exportReport('EXCEL');" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none;">Excel</a>
</div>
```

I tried using the following to find the element:
* Using getcssSelector
* Using linkText

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Tried Xpath. The xpath I get when copying is below: //*[@id="ctl31_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu"]/div[5]/a . Before adding it to the parameter, I escaped the quotation marks, which changes the xpath to the below driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl31_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu\"]/div[5]/a")).click(); Unfortunately it does not give me a error, but also does not do anything. Thanks for the help thus far

Comment: What happens when you use `By.LinkText("Excel")`? Please post the code you have tried and what the result was... error message, etc.

Comment: Is there any exception with your tried attempt??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps to get the xpath from chrome:**

1. Right click on the element on the webpage and click inspect
2. The HTML for the element should be highlighted
3. Right click on the highlighted section
4. Hover over 'copy'
5. Click Copy xpath

Then to find the element use:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Paste Xpath here"));
```

To click on it then:

```
element.click();
```

Comment: The xpath I am getting is below. //*[@id="ctl31_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu"]/div[5]/a which is not working unfortunately

Comment: You need to remove the double quotes in the xpath and replace with single quotes - //*[@id='ctl31_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu']/div[5]/a

Comment: Gives no error, but doesn't do anything either. I used element.getText(); to confirm the element is correct. It prints the label correctly. So I believe the element is correct, but it does not want to click on it.

Comment: try: 
element.sendKeys("");
element.click();

Comment: element.sendKeys(""); element.click(); worked perfectly!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!